# Is there a way to cancel the start depending on a condition with FastAPI startup event?

Tags: startup, fastapi, starlette

What I want to do is check a condition on startup event and if execption occurs do not start server or stop server.

```
@app.on_event("startup")
def startup_event():
    public_key = None

    try:
        with open(PUBLIC_KEY_FILE) as public_key_file:
            public_key = public_key_file.read()
    except Exception as f_error:
        logger.exception(f_error)

        # cancel the startup
```

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Raise an exception in startup function:

```py
@app.on_event("startup")
def startup_event():
    public_key = None

    try:
        with open(PUBLIC_KEY_FILE) as public_key_file:
            public_key = public_key_file.read()
    except Exception as f_error:
        logger.exception(f_error)

        raise SomeException()
```